# Get shortest match with regex - lazy quantifier

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract some strings from a legal text where the patterns are repeated several times.

I am not sure I understand how the lazy quantifier (?) works. From what I read it is supposed to capture a match using as few characters as possible. However it doesnt seem to do that in my example below:

Sorry for the text in spanish, but I guess it is simple enough to follow.

> ...por la afirmativa.los señores jueces doctores genoud, hitters, de
>   lazzari, roncoroni y soria, por los mismos fundamentos de la señora
>   jueza doctora kogan, votaron la primera cuestion planteada tambien por
>   la negativa.a la tercera cuestion planteada, la señora jueza doctora
>   kogan dijo:..(text)...voto por la afirmativa.los señores jueces
>   doctores genoud e hitters, por los mismos fundamentos de la señora
>   jueza doctora kogan, votaron la tercera cuestion planteada por la
>   afirmativa.a la tercera cuestion planteada, el señor juez doctor de
>   lazzari dijo:...

I am trying to capture the text between the strings "**los señores jueces**" (line 4) and "**votaron la tercera cuestion planteada por la afirmativa**" . There are two matches for this pattern as the string "los señores jueces" appears twice, once at the beginning and then in line 4.

So I try to use the lazy quantifier (.*?) to get the shortest of the 2 matches:

```
(los señores jueces(.*?)votaron la tercera cuestion planteada por la afirmativa)
```

But it doesnt seem to work, it matches the longest string, starting from line 1 and not from the second (shortest) occurrence. I am testing the regex on https://regex101.com/

Apreciate any help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: That's not how the lazy quantifier works. In fact the lazy quantifier doesn't get you anything here.

Comment: The lazy quantifier affects how a match is selected from a set of possible matches in the _current position_. It doesn't affect the choice of the matching position - it's always the leftmost possible one. So the RE engine scans your string, finds the "begin" string, scans further until it encounters the "end" string, stops there and makes no further attempts to find a "better" match.

Comment: Thanks for clarifiying georg, I was missinterpreting the use of the lazy quantifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead to force the regex engine to check that there isn't a string `los señores jueces` present, before matching each character.

```
los señores jueces((?:(?!los señores jueces).)*?)votaron la tercera cuestion planteada por la afirmativa
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jO6zT2/12)

Comment: Thank you Avinash! Works perfectly. Seems look ahead will solve most of my problems. I marking this as answered. Rgds.

Comment: i used the first part inside the negative lookahead , you could  use the last part also.